# Faster alternative for nested for loop time wise

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

I need to calculate/from a list of possible integers formed by

**i + 2j + k**, where 1 <= i,j,k <= N.

I know it will be all integers from 4 to 4N, but I also need their frequencies, hence have to formulate a list. I couldn't find pattern for the frequencies either. My brute force approach was:

For n = 2, list would be like : [4,5,6,5,7,6,7,8]

```
for i in range(N+1):
  for j in range(N+1):
     for k in range(N+1):
         #creating a list
```

Else is there a pattern to it? Like if i+2j+k = P,
Frequency of P = some equation in form of P. As far as i tried, didn't find any linear or quadratic equation.

Its complexity is O^3, so I need a better version/alternative of the same. I'm open to ideas. And please ask if you don't understand something.

Comment: Try this in reverse, given a value, can you come up with a formula that specifies the number of times it will be part of the list?

Comment: Why is this exponential?

Comment: Could you please specify what goes on in "creating a list"? And perhaps what input / output do you expect for some (small) value of N?

Comment: So, essentially, you need all combinations of 3-integer-tuples, with integers being between 4 and N?

Comment: Complexity is O(N^3), not exponential.

Comment: Why your loops limits are (4, 4 * N) while earlier you state that 1< i,j,k < N?

Comment: Right, that's my type error.

Comment: This problem is not very well-specified; do you want a list of the same elements in the same order, or just the same elements with the same number of occurrences? Is the lower bound 1 < i,j,k as stated in your question, or 0 <= i,j,k as implied by your code? Is the upper bound "less than N" as stated in your question, or less than N+1 as implied by your code?

Comment: I don't quite get it: _"but I also need their frequencies"_ this indicates that you need also the single combinations and as such you can't have it cheaper than O^3 - unless you don't care for the places where the numbers go.

Comment: @kaya3 its not required to have same elements in same order. And i need all elements not just element with the same occurrences. And bound is as implied by my code.

Comment: *"I need all elements not just element with the same occurrences"* - what does that mean? Do you need them in the same order, or not? But if you actually need all the results in a list, including duplicates, then the output size is O(n^3) so of course you can't produce that output in asymptotically less time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since noboding is posting a linear solution ( I am sure there is one), I will post a quadratic one:

```
def ways(n,N):
    s=0
    s1 = 0
    s2 = 0


    for j in range(1,N+1):
        if n - 2*j < 2:
            break
        if n - 2*j > 2*N:
            continue
        s1+= min(n-2*j - 1,N) +1
        s2+= max(n-2*j-N, 1)

    return s1 - s2


N=2
print({ i: ways(i,N) for i in range(4, 4*N+1) })
```

outputs:

```
{4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 1}
```

At least an improvement from O(N^3) to O(N^2).

Comment: Excellent approach, i guess O(N^2) might do the trick. Thanks  man!